# What is benefits of using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs

What are benefits of using nodeJS as running environment for react.

P.S I’ve seen project that uses react front, which is sending request on same port to node and after that node was sending request to server.(react and node were in same folder)

on npm start was running server.js which was reading data from react build.

I’m interested why not to send request from react itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- beacause npm is the package manager for the Node JavaScript platform. It puts modules in place so that node can find them, and manages dependency conflicts intelligently.

it is extremely configurable to support a wide variety of use cases. Most commonly, it is used to publish, discover, install, and develop node programs. so it optional to use node js in your platforme*

**it give you a good technical stack:**
*By using JavaScript on the server side in the backend and on the frontend interface side with the different frontend frameworks such as React.Js, Next.Js, Vue.Js or Angular.Js, your web application uses JavaScript everywhere.*